# ¿Cómo puedo colocar un progress bar en modo indeterminate con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Este es mi cuerpo:

```
<div class="shadow w-full bg-blue-lighter progress" >
             <div class="bg-blue text-xs leading-none py-1 text-center text-white" id="progress_line"></div>
         </div>
```

Y estos son mis Scripts, por ahora solo tengo la carga de progreso ya que no encuentro componentes para hacer otro progress bar pero de modo indeterminate:

```
<script>
   function progress () {
      let elem = document.getElementById('progress_line'),
          width = 1,
          id = setInterval(progressStatus,50);
          function progressStatus () {
              if (width >= 100) {
                 clearInterval(id); 
              } else {
                  width++;
                  elem.style.width = width + '%';
              }
          }

   }
   progress();
</script>
```